# Need advise for DataStructure like Tuple or keyValuePair but mutable type

Tags: c#, generics, data-structures, key-value

I need a type like a `Tuple` or `KeyValuePair` type and with option to sets its values (mutable type).
Any ideas of existing generics that would fulfill these needs?

(Dictionary seems to me to be some kind of overkill for my purpose)

I can write my own class as well, but I was hoping that there is some mutable type of `KeyValuePair` already implemented.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with having a mutable is that you can very easily end up referencing the same tuple multiple times where you change the value in one place it will also change in other places where you don't expect it to. So if you do use mutable tubles you will have to be very stringent about cloning the tuple at the appropriate places, for example if you put it into a collection.

But a mutable tuple would look something like this:

```
public class MutableTuple<T1, T2> {
    public T1 Item1 { get; set; }
    public T2 Item2 { get; set; }

    public MutableTuple(T1 item1, T2 item2) {
        Item1 = item1;
        Item2 = item2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite enough. Tuples have equality and hash code implementations by default.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MutableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. Unless you consider `object[]` to be one :-)

Note that implementing a `MutableTuple<T1, ...>` is quite easy.

A full implementation of a `MutableTuple<T1, T2, T3>`, nearly equivalent to a `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>` (the various interfaces are implemented publicly and not privately) (partially based on the Mono implementation of `Tuple<>`)

```
public static class MutableTuple
{
    public static MutableTuple<T1, T2, T3> Create<T1, T2, T3>(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3)
    {
        return new MutableTuple<T1, T2, T3>(item1, item2, item3);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class MutableTuple<T1, T2, T3> : IComparable, IStructuralEquatable, IStructuralComparable
{
    public T1 Item1 { get; set; }
    public T2 Item2 { get; set; }
    public T3 Item3 { get; set; }

    public MutableTuple(T1 item1, T2 item2, T3 item3)
    {
        this.Item1 = item1;
        this.Item2 = item2;
        this.Item3 = item3;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals(obj, EqualityComparer<object>.Default);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.GetHashCode(EqualityComparer<object>.Default);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append(this.Item1);
        sb.Append(", ");
        sb.Append(this.Item2);
        sb.Append(", ");
        sb.Append(this.Item3);
        sb.Append(")");

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return this.CompareTo(obj, Comparer<object>.Default);
    }

    public bool Equals(object obj, IEqualityComparer comparer)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var tuple = obj as MutableTuple<T1, T2, T3>;
        return tuple != null && (comparer.Equals(this.Item1, tuple.Item1) && comparer.Equals(this.Item2, tuple.Item2)) && comparer.Equals(this.Item3, tuple.Item3);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEqualityComparer comparer)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;

            hash = (hash * 23) + comparer.GetHashCode(this.Item1);
            hash = (hash * 23) + comparer.GetHashCode(this.Item2);
            hash = (hash * 23) + comparer.GetHashCode(this.Item3);

            return hash;
        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj, IComparer comparer)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        var other = obj as MutableTuple<T1, T2, T3>;

        if (other == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        int res = comparer.Compare(this.Item1, other.Item1);

        if (res != 0)
        {
            return res;
        }

        res = comparer.Compare(this.Item2, other.Item2);

        if (res != 0)
        {
            return res;
        }

        res = comparer.Compare(this.Item3, other.Item3);

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: There exists [`DictionaryEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionaryentry.aspx) which is a mutable pair, but it has two problems: (1) It is not generic/type-safe. (2) It is a mutable value type.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You are right... I didn't know. We could even add that one problem is that it's a `struct` :-) For Tuple they thought very hard and chosed `class`es. And the second one (it's a mutable value type) is a feature, not a bug :-)

Comment: A good complete answer. Few comments, 1) why do you use non generic comparer for equality and hash codes to cause boxing? 2) Is string builder worth it in place of 6 string concatenations? 3) `Mutuple` would have been a better naming :D

Comment: @nawfal 1) because the interface `IStructuralEquatable` is done that way. 2) probably yes, but it depends on the length of the substrings. For example if `this.Item1` == `this.Item2` == `this.Item3` == "" then a simple string concatenation would be better. But remember that this is an example of code. You would have to implement it for various numbers of parameters (`Tuple<...>` goes up to eight). With 8 parameters the `StringBuilder` would be faster. 3) I'm not very strong with naming. When I work I try to make my colleagues or my boss choose names.

Comment: 1) `IStructuralEquatable` may be that way, but wouldn't it be better to go about `public override bool Equals(object obj)` in a generic fashion, without changing resultant behaviour? But I see the framework itself implements as you have shown :(. 3) Well I was joking with that :)